# Unable to save the Edited content through PUT method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the request from the server. After that , when i click on the toggle_edit() , the data content should get edited and when i click on the toggle_save() , the edited contents should get saved and it should be updated in json server. But when i click on the save button , It generates 405 error and Method Not Allowed.

Html code :

```
<div ng-show="contact" id="contacts_edit()">
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="toggle_edit()"> Edit </button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="toggle_save(cts.selectedcontact)"> Save </button>          
</div>
<b> Street:</b> 
<p ng-hide="editMode">                                              
    {{cts.selectedcontact.location.street}} 
</p>
<input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="cts.selectedcontact.location.street"><br/>
```

Angular code :

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(contacts,data){

            $scope.selectedcontact = {};

            $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + contacts.id)

                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                        $scope.cts.selectedcontact = data;
                    })
                }
```

Comment: What server side technology are you using?

Comment: Also, double check your API endpoint. just maybe missing something there. that put URL looks off.

Comment: json -server...

Comment: I need to send the response data. But i am quite confused in calling it